# Data from post in ajax request works but PHP still says undefined index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is pretty weird to me and I can't seem to find what's wrong.
I'll elaborate on what I'm doing now.

- I have this page called "categoriasCatalogo.php" where I want a navbar to appear, I have this navbar in another file named "navbar.php".
- I have an Ajax request sending the level of navbar I want and the catalog's ID, it's correctly routed and the navbar displays *properly*, the payload has the correct data and the correct names, but I get an error saying the navbarlv index is undefined. Which cannot be as both match and as I said, the navbar is displaying and working.
- This aproach worked in another file without any issues, only difference being the other file is in the root folder like navbar.php.

I'll provide some stuff that might be useful:

- This is the Ajax request, executed on the document.ready function in the "categoriasCatalogo.php" file, located in the bottom part of the code, making sure the container that will hold the navbar exists.

```
const getNavBar = (idcat) => {
        let paquete = "navbarlv=2&idcatalogo="+idcat;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../navbar.php",
            data: paquete,
            dataType: "html"
        }).fail(function(respuesta) {
            //TODO: Modal fail
        }).done(function(respuesta) {
            document.getElementById("navbarlvl2").innerHTML = respuesta;
            
        })
    }
```

- Var_dump($navbarLV) returns this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: navbarlv in C:\laragon\www\McPDF\navbar.php on line 3
NULL
string(1) "2"
```

- Var_dump($_POST) returns this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: navbarlv in C:\laragon\www\McPDF\navbar.php on line 3
array(0) { }
array(2) { ["navbarlv"]=> string(1) "2" ["idcatalogo"]=> string(1) "9" }
```

- print_r($_POST) returns this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: navbarlv in C:\laragon\www\McPDF\navbar.php on line 3
Array ( )
Array ( [navbarlv] => 2 [idcatalogo] => 9 )
```

What's calling my attention is that empty array, I don't know where that is coming from.

- Raw payload looks like this:

```
navbarlv=2&idcatalogo=9
```

- The beggining of "navbar.php" looks like this, the catalog ID ("idcatalogo") is requested within the function navbarlvl2() and it's working:

```
require_once "config.php";
$navbarLV = $_POST["navbarlv"];

switch($navbarLV){
    case "1":
        navbarlvl1();
        break;
    case "2":
        navbarlvl2();
        break;
}
```

As requested, here are the screenshots:

[Image of where I'm getting this error, now with var_dump($_POST)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sLAY.png)

[Response, along with the whole network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwmAm.png)

This is my very first post here, thanks a lot in advance and hope you're having a nice day :)

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: Try sticking a `die(print_r($_POST));` at the top of your navbar.php to see what it is receiving

Comment: Hi! Tried both of your suggestions and var_dump($_POST) shows: array(0) { } ---- And die(print_r($_POST)); shows: Array () 1. Decided to check the file that's working and it's showing this: array(1) { ["navbarlv"]=> string(1) "1" } . Clearly something's wrong but the navbar is working

Comment: The payload you show looks like JSON.

Comment: Why do you have `echo` before `var_dump()`?

Comment: `NULL` is coming from `var_dump($navbarLV)`. `string(1) "2"` is coming from something else in the script.

Comment: That's how Mozilla is presenting it, but the raw payload is still "navbarlv=2&idcatalogo=9". That echo before var_dump() was redundant as I just saw, thanks. I'll edit the post now but it's showing this: array(0) { }
array(2) { ["navbarlv"]=> string(1) "2" ["idcatalogo"]=> string(1) "9" }

Comment: @Phil I have no clue, I followed the steps of the file that does work and there it shows only 1 output line. The function is only being called once in the entire file. I'll be taking another deep look to the whole procedure anyway.

Comment: @Phil yes, it's added via .innerHTML = respuesta. The response is the expected one, all the html code that's going into the <navbar> with the "navbarlvl2" id. Should have pointed this but essentially, the functions in "navbar.php" just echo the html code to insert via innerHTML.

Comment: It's difficult to understand the context of your _return_ examples. Any chance you could add a screenshot to your question (you can paste screenshots directly from your clipboard into the question editor)? Could you also provide the code exactly as it appears currently in `navbar.php`, at least the first 5 - 10 lines. And finally, make sure you use the browser dev-tools for debugging, particularly the _Network_ panel

Comment: By context do you mean where exactly I'm getting this error? I'll be happy to show it. Also, the code in navbar.php is pasted in the bottom of the question, the only thing that shouldn't be there is the var_dump, I'll remove that now.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Please include the `var_dump` and what it displays when you add the response. The most confusing part in all this is the double `var_dump` output; there should be only one line. If you could include screenshots of the actual response from your _Network_ panel, that would also be very helpful

Comment: @Phil You got it, give me a minute

Comment: Are you by any chance including `navbar.php` in `categoriasCatalogo.php`, eg `include '../navbar.php';`? If so, don't do that

Comment: Oh my god. @Phil that was it, I was including navbar.php in categoriasCatalogo.php. Maybe at some point I thought about just calling the function directly instead of using Ajax or something. Thanks a lot, to you and everyone who took the time to help :)